# SQL Server query where condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We are using the below SQL fragment in the `where` condition of a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
convert(varchar, CreateDate, 101) <= convert(varchar, GETDATE() - @numberofdays, 101)
```

- Datatype of `CreateDate` is `datetime`
- Datatype of `@numberofdays` is `int`

Can you please confirm if this condition will work fine or it can fail in any scenario as the datatypes are converted to varchar before comparing dates?

Comment: Why are you converting them to string before comparing them ?, you can already compare them as datetime.

Comment: Also: `GETDATE() - @NumberOfDays` is not very clear - are you **sure** the minus operator will subtract days? That's an assumption.... I'd recommend using `DATEADD(DAYS, -1 * @numberofdays, GETDATE())` to be crystal clear and obvious. Also: you should **always** specify an **explicit length** for a `varchar` - otherwise, you might end up with a nasty surprise when an unexpected default length kicks in .....

Comment: @MarcGuillot The expression GETDATE() - NumberOfDays is returning the correct output by subtracting the number of days. Do you know if there is any performance impact using GETDATE() - NumberOfDays. If yes then we can use dateadd() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CreateDate <= DATEADD(day,-1*@numberofdays,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Tapakah, but does query written above in my question is wrong or will it give incorrect output?

Comment: Rigth compare datetime type

Comment: @bhanu it will give you incorrect output, returning 12/01/2016 as greater than 01/01/2017. If you really need strings, you should use format 111 instead, 2016/12/01 is smaller than 2017/01/01.

Comment: @bhanu except for the extra conversion and problems with the format, you lose the ability to use indexes for this field

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work.

See below queries

```
declare @numberofdays int
set @numberofdays=3

declare @CreateDate datetime
set @CreateDate= '2017-03-20'

select
convert(varchar,@CreateDate, 101) as date1,
convert(varchar,GETDATE()- @numberofdays,101) as date2
```

output from them is

```
date1   date2
03/20/2017  10/08/2017
```

Which is in same format and will work

<kbd>**[working demo](http://rextester.com/LPDPD70630)**</kbd>

Comment: It won't raise an exception but it will allow 2016 dates (such as 12/01/2016) to be considered greater than 2017 dates (such as 01/01/2017).

Comment: If he insists on converting them to string, he should be using format 111 instead (yyyy/mm/dd)